# How did Viola in "Suburra" know where to find Samurai?

Tags: plot-explanation, suburra

In the 2015 movie [*Suburra*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4025514/), there is the drug using girlfriend of Number 8, who ends up killing Samurai, a high-level mafioso.

Is there any hint in the book or in the movie how this happened? How did she find him?